# Why do i get Stack overflow error in SAS while running stepwise regression

Tags: sas, regression

I try to run stepwise regression in sas with 2.9M rows with 300 columns. I am getting below error.

`ERROR: Event Stack Overflow. This is probably caused by mis-matched begin and end event calls.`

My Code is

```
* Forward Selection;
proc reg data =work.bs_bm_final_data outest=est1; 
    model  y =  A_004 - A_300 / selection = forward slentry = 0.99 ss2 sse aic; 
output out=out1 p=p r=r; run; quit;
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have mismatched begin and end event calls?

Comment: I m new to sas. how do i check begin nd end event calls. This query i am getting from google

Comment: That was apparently a sarcastic comment... that's not a thing in SAS, this is something not working right inside SAS itself.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a problem with your version of SAS or something around your machine's configuration. For a server this would be a relatively small dataset but for a consumer desktop or laptop it could be too much.

Can you try running `proc glmselect` instead and see if it works? The adapted code is below.

```
proc glmselect data=sashelp.cars;
    model y = A_004 - A_300 / selection=forward(sle=0.99) showpvalues;
    output out=out p=p r=r;
run;
```

Otherwise, [SAS Tech Support](https://support.sas.com/en/technical-support.html) would be a good option to contact.